# Finding $\sqrt{x^2+x}$ when $x^2$ = $\sqrt{x}$ but $x^2$ $\neq$ $x$ (And where x is a complex number)

Tags: complex-numbers

Original Problem: If the square of a number is equal to the square root of a number but not equal to the number, what is the value of the square root of the sum of the number and the number squared?

So far i've tried experimenting with i to see how that affects the values of $x^2$, $\sqrt{x}$, and x, but haven't been able to make to much progress.

Any ideas? All help is appreciated.

Comment: You tagged this "complex numbers" but $\sqrt{x}$ is not in general defined for for $x$ complex (it has multiple values) unless you make a certain choice which you should specify. Is this really about complex numbers?

Comment: $x^4=x\implies x(x^3-1)=0 \implies x=0$ or $x=1 $ but there is no solution to your problem since $0=0^2$ and $1=1^2$

Comment: This problem is for my math class, and I was explicitly told that the solution was a complex number by my teacher, so this problem is about complex numbers. I'll specify that in the title.

Comment: @Yassir $x^4 = x$ has another two complex roots besides $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Based on all the comments and the answer, you should be able to figure out (unambiguously) the value of $x^2+x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^2=\sqrt{x}\implies x^4=x\implies x=0,1,\omega,\omega^2$ where $\omega$ is a cube root of unity.

$\color{red}{If}$ you don't mind the informality of writing $$\sqrt{\omega^2}=\omega$$
then the only valid solution is $$x=\omega^2$$
and you probably know that $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$, so can you calculate the answer?

Answer (score 1):

> the original problem: If the square of a number is equal to the square root of a number but not equal to the number, what is the value of the square root of the sum of the number and the number squared?

The original problem refers to “the” square root (singular), Yassir's comment shows that no solution exists in the real world; so, we must define the principal square root of a complex number. Letting **the principal root of $x$ be the root with the smallest nonnegative argument** and denoting this as $\sqrt x:$ \begin{align}\Big(x^2=\sqrt x \;\text{and}\;x^2\ne x\Big)&\iff x=e^{-i\frac{2\pi}3}\\\sqrt{x^2+x}=&\sqrt{e^{-i\frac{4\pi}3}+e^{-i\frac{2\pi}3}}\\=&\sqrt{e^{i\frac{2\pi}3}+e^{i\frac{4\pi}3}}\\=&\sqrt{2\Re (e^{i\frac{2\pi}3})}\\=&\sqrt{-1}\\=&e^{i\frac{\pi}3}.\end{align}